# Why does a C++ pointer to char act as a character string despite the lack of a null terminator?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, pointers

As I understand it C-style strings, even when used in C++ instead of the string class, need a null terminating character:

```
This is a string.\0
```

It is also my understanding that the lack of a null character causes the program to continue reading whatever comes in memory after the string until it finds the binary representation of the null character. This is very clearly undefined behavior.

When writing a dtoi function (I wanted to write this myself for practice as part of a different practice project I am doing -- I know there are library facilities to do this already), I found different behaviour (specifically, when creating the string for the `invalid_argument` exception).

```
int dtoi(const char d){
    switch(d){ //using switch statement rather than d-'0' to support character sets with non-consecutive digits or digits that go from 9 to 0 rather than 0 to 9
        case '0':
            return 0;
        case '1':
            return 1;
        case '2':
            return 2;
        case '3':
            return 3;
        case '4':
            return 4;
        case '5':
            return 5;
        case '6':
            return 6;
        case '7':
            return 7;
        case '8':
            return 8;
        case '9':
            return 9;
        default:
            throw invalid_argument(((d == '\0') ? "null character" : &d) + string(" is not a valid digit character."));
    }
}
```

As a null character at the start of the exception string caused it to end at the first character (ie. when a null character was passed to my implementation of dtoi), I decided to have it display the text "null character" instead of directly inserting the character if it is `'\0'`. To implement this, I use the conditional operator. I can't use `(d == '\0') ? "null character" : d` (notice how it says `d` not `&d` at the end) because then the conditional operator may return either a pointer to the first character in the string literal or a character directly. To see what happened, I decided to try `&d` and, to my surprise, it printed whatever character was passed into the function in exception.what(). I would expect it to provide a pointer to the passed character, but, to then continue reading into random memory until it found a null character. I tried this multiple times with multiple different characters passed in. Why does it behave as it is? Am I actually right about it being undefined behavior, and it just happens to work as intended here?

Comment: Because undefined behaviour.

Comment: To anyone who is downvoting: I'm not sure why you are doing this -- it seems like a valid question. I am asking if a specific action is in fact undefined behavior or if I am misunderstanding how C++ works. If this is somehow invalid, please tell me rather than giving downvotes.

Comment: @juanchopanza That sounds very much like an answer.

Comment: "character sets with non-consecutive digits or digits that go from 9 to 0 rather than 0 to 9" There is no such thing.

Comment: The C and C++ standards both say that digits `0` through `9` are consecutive and in that order

Comment: @M.M I didn't know it was in the standard. The book I am learning from simply said that it was the case with ASCII and Unicode. In that case, how should I throw an exception if invalid input is passed?

Comment: do `throw` whenever you deem the input to be invalid

Comment: @M.M I understand that, but, I figured a switch statement was a good way to both check for invalid input and deal with the problem of character sets (which I now know isn't a problem). Are you saying I should have a switch or if statement check for valid numbers and throw an exception, but, use `'0'-c` when there is valid input?

Comment: @john01dav IDK what you consider valid or invalid. write logic that detects whatever cases you want to consider invalid, and then `throw` in those cases

Comment: @M.M I consider the digits 0-9 valid. It seems redundant to first detect if it is a digit and then use `'0'-c` to find the actual digit  -- it seems simpler to combine them in one step as I did with the switch statement. I don't understand why that approach is bad.

Comment: There's no evidence that the program *doesn't* "continue reading into random memory until it found a null character". The "random memory" after `&d` may contain zero.

Comment: well, it's not terrible, but it's overly verbose. You could replace 20 lines with 2: `if ( d >= '0' && d <= '9' ) return d - '0';` (with line break). I think most people would prefer to read the latter

Comment: @M.M Alright, thank you for the information :)

Comment: @molbdnilo I figured that the chances of there being a null character immediately after the character on multiple occasions to be very low. It even behaved as intended (ie. as if there was a null) if the character cam from a std::string with non-null characters after the digit character.

Comment: The chance of zero bytes on the stack is higher than expected. Pointers hold memory addresses which tend to have the high order byte zero. Local variables in previous function calls on the same place on the stack  may have been explicitly zero-initialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This `operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) is used here (a pointer to single `char` that is not null-terminated is not really suitable). Yes, most definitely [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

> `lhs` -   string, character, or pointer to the first character in a null-terminated array

Just make `std::string` the common type to fix it:

```
((d == '\0') ? std::string("null character") : std::string(1, d))
```

---

And don't form `switch`-`case` statements like that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question though, what is wrong with my switch-case? Is it simply because the standard defines 0-9 as guaranteed? If so, how should I implement an exception on invalid input?

Comment: @john01dav T.C. and M.M explained. You'll be fine with `d - '0'` and some `if`-statements.

Answer (score 3):

There is one basic thing you need to know about C-Style strings, the way we represent them (char array with a '\0' at the end) is just a convention, there is no type (in C) for strings. This means that, from a language point of view, there is no difference between a pointer to a single char and a pointer to the start of a char array (that may be a string). So it's up a the function using such a pointer to interpret it in a good way, and for that documentation is your friend.

Since you're using C++, I strongly advise you to use std::string only and keep C-Style strings for backward compatibility with C libraries, you'll avoid a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is undefined behavior, because you read random memory. What you should do instead of the whole messy switch and the `?:` operator is this:

```
#include <cctype>

if(!std::isdigit(d))
{
  std::string err_str;

  if(d == '\0')
  {
    err_str = "Null character";
  }
  else
  {
    err_str = std::string(1, d);
  }
  err_str += " is not a valid digit character.";

  throw invalid_argument(err_str);
}

return (int)d - '0';
```